# JPQL Left join with filtering on one-to-many collection

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, entity, hql, jpql

i have two entities, user and activity in a one-to-many relationship, where user have many activities. my goal is to retrieve all the users with a subset of activities based on a condition. for example, i would like to retrieve all the users and the associated activities that are in "pending" status. it is possible that user may not have any pending activities. in this case i you like to have the user with no activity.

how can i write a JPQL for this.

thanks you in advance for your help

Comment: Fine, make sense what you have tried so far?

Comment: ** select u from User u left join u.activity a where a.state = 'Pending' **. but this doesn't work the way i wanted

Comment: Kindly update your question with some database information

Answer (score 0):

you can do this set association like in your entity:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Activities
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="Activity_Id")
    private Activity Activity;

    public Activity getActivity(){
        this.Activity
    }
```

While when your Queries:

```
List<User> toReturn= new ArrayList<>();
    Query query = em.createQuery("select u from User u ");
    List<User> list = query.getResultList();
    for(User u : list){
        if(u.getActivity().getStatus().equal("PENDING")){
            toReturn.add(u);
            //Some of your business Logic
        }
        //Some of your business Logic
    }
```

Hope helped!

Answer (score 0):

In JPA 2.1 the `JOIN ON` was introduced, but I am not sure it can be combined with `FETCH`.
Basically I recommend trying the following query:

```
SELECT u from User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.activity a ON a.state = 'Pending'
```

If you do not have JPA 2.1 or if the above solution does not work, then you will have to take the Users and load their activities afterwards (in a single query) or load the users with all their activities and filter them, as Sarz wrote in his/her answer.